# Compiler Issue or Improper State Variable declaration?

Tags: solidity, remix, solc

After seeing some unexpected compiler results, I've reduced the issue to this tiny example:

The following compiles under 0.4.10 in Remix:

```
contract StorageMapping {

    struct S {
        mapping(bytes32 => uint) m;
        bytes32[] b;
        uint x;
    }

    mapping(bytes32 => S) public sStructs;

}
```

However, the following fails to compile with "**Internal** Type is not allowed for state variable, referring to the mapping. Spot checked 3.x and 2.x. Result is consistent back to version 0.2.1 (0.2.0 throws *internal compiler error*).

Only difference in the contracts is the one line commented out.

```
contract StorageMapping {

    struct S {
        mapping(bytes32 => uint) m;
        bytes32[] b;
        // uint x;
    }

    mapping(bytes32 => S) public sStructs;

}
```

The important thing seems to be to add a simple value to the struct (even if not needed). This makes me wonder what's really going on.

Does anyone know a reason why the **mapped struct seems to need at least one simple value to avoid confusion**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to chriseth for pointing out that's not possible to assemble a getter for sStructs when the structs contain only indexed types. Since it is declared `public`, the compiler is not happy about being asked to create an impossible getter.

Remove `public` and both flavors and compile.