# Iniitalize struct in struct

Tags: solidity, arrays, struct

How I do I push the first value to this:

```
  struct Balance {
    address owner;
    uint amount;
    DeepBalance[] deepBalance;

  }

  struct DeepBalance{
    address swap ;
    uint amount ;
  }
Balance[] balances;
```

this doesn't work, but is what I feel in the bottom of my heart is close:

```
DeepBalance[] memory deepBalance;
balances.push(Balance({
  owner: 0,
  amount: 0,
  deepBalance: DeepBalance({
      swap: 0,
      amount: 0
  })
}));
```

Comment: If you just want to nest them, check this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/22887/23354).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it's currently not possible to achieve what you want to do.

As @toothleth_byte proposed in his comment, you could look [at this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/22887/23354) but it will only work with mappings, not arrays.

What you could do is to use a mapping and also store the unique ids of the mapping elements in an array if you want the ability to loop through the elements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I ended up doing just that, but it is a little disappointing having to waste more gas for little quirks like this